# Open an external XML file

Tags: android, xml

Is it possible to open an external file in Android (as XmlPullParser)?

Comment: External as in from the web, packaged w/ your app or stored on the sdcard? All of these are possible but each has a unique method of retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File f = new File(filePath);
reader = new FileReader(f);
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(reader);
```

That's how do I.

Answer (score 1):

See `android.util.Xml` and its `newPullParser()` method.

As the documentation for it indicates, XPP is not faster than SAX. Hence, unless you are a big fan of the XPP programming model, I would use SAX, just because it is more commonly used in Java.